# url will not load in webview

Tags: php, android, android-webview

I have an application that has a fragment that contains a web view. The web view functions properly when I try other URLs however when I attempt to use "http://peekatu.com/scraper/onair.php" it will not load in the web view. I have no idea as to why it won't load. Help is appreciated. Thank you.

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub



        View v= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_listen_live, container, false);
        btn = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        btn.setOnClickListener(pausePlay);
        web_v= (WebView) v.findViewById(R.id.webView);
        WebSettings web_sett=web_v.getSettings();
        web_sett.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        //web_v.setWebViewClient(new MyWebClient());
        web_v.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        web_v.loadUrl("http://peekatu.com/scraper/onair.php");

        MainActivity m = (MainActivity) getActivity();
        m.changeMenu("homePage");
        this.getSherlockActivity().getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Power 92 Chicago");
        this.getSherlockActivity().getSupportActionBar()
                .setSubtitle("#1 in the Streets!");


        return v;
    }


 private class MyWebClient extends WebViewClient {

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            web_v.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }


    }
```

onair.php

```
<?php

set_time_limit(0);
ignore_user_abort(FALSE);
error_reporting(E_ERROR);
ini_set('display_errors', 'on');

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.power92chicago.com/');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.99 Safari/537.36');

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])) {
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
}


$dom = new DOMDocument();

$dom->loadHTML(curl_exec($ch));

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$node = $xpath->query("//td[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' TimeFeatureHorizontalTd ')]")->item(0);


echo get_inner_html($node);



function get_inner_html($node) { 
    $innerHTML= ''; 
    $children = $node->childNodes; 
    foreach ($children as $child) { 
        $innerHTML .= $child->ownerDocument->saveXML( $child ); 
    } 
    
    return $innerHTML;
}

?>
```

Comment: Have you added INTERNET permission ?

Comment: yes. the web view can load other urls just fine.

Comment: other urls from the same domain?

Comment: yes. i can load. peekatu.com just fine. or even peekatu.com/blank.html

Comment: is there any thing special i need to do to load a .php file?

Answer (score 0):

Before you call `loadUrl`, add this line:

```
web_v.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
```

Also, I don't know why you define a `WebViewClient` that overrides `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` and then calls `loadUrl` yourself - just remove that.

Comment: I have added that line but the url still does not load. I have update the code in my question to reflect the changes made.

Answer (score 0):

Testing with the mobile browser the webpage doesn't load so the problem is definetly not in your android code, the problem is on the php code.

Can you share the code to generate that web?

Also if what you are trying to do is show information in your app you might need to think a different approach, if you want to display a list of data in your app, you might want to use a listView and getting the data from a JSON REST Api rather than displaying that list in a php website

Comment: Thank you. I have added the php code to my original question.